# List of companies working in core networking domain?

Tags: networking

I would like to know the name of companies working in core networking and embedded domain.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Rupesh

Comment: Thanks, But this is in general question about career-development, which i thought i can post under career-development tag [As per name of tag represents].

Comment: @Bart K.
@this.__curious_geek
@David M
@Amarghosh 
@Douglas Leeder = Alright! then remove the career-development tag from stackoverflow. It should not be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cisco, SMC, HP, Dell, Verizon, AT&T, EMC